# Debug exe code in visual studio

Tags: c++

There is an exe created in c++. I can run this from command prompt with required arguments.
Is there a way to debug this exe code in visual studio after started through cmd prompt?

Comment: There's `Debug->Attach` or something IIRC.

Comment: on the flipside, you can set the command line arguments and working dir via visual studio n project settings, and then run the debugger normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Sleep()` somewhere before a breakpoint that you set and build your project. Run the newly built application from the command line and in VS go to `Tools -> Attach to process`, look for your application and attach before the `Sleep()` expires. A good value for sleep is `10000`, that means you have 10 seconds to attach before the sleep expires.

After the sleep is over it should hit the breakpoint provided the source code hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is running on Windows, you can programatically detect if a debugger is present and Sleep or change behavoir while it isn't.

```
// Wait for debugger to be attached...
while(!IsDebuggerPresent())
{
    Sleep(10);
}
```

Note though, changing behavior substantially when a debugger is attached is a recipe for really hard to find bugs, so use this sparingly.